# Error while configuring PyQt 4.11.3

Tags: compiler-errors, pyqt, qmake

I try to install PyQt to develop Python apps using Qt on fedora 20. I downloaded SIP and PyQt4 from http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk and compiled the packages.
But I encountered a problem while compiling PyQt4:

I ran python configure.py in the Terminal and I got:

> Error: Make sure you have a working Qt v4 qmake on your PATH or use
>   the -q argument to explicitly specify a working Qt v4 qmake.

And i am unable to find qmake.
Any help will be appriciated.